# Why bool(None and None is None) is False?

Tags: python

If `None and None` returns `None`, `(None and None is None)` should return `True`, No?

Was debugging an app and noticed that it returns `None`

Comment: Your assumptions about operator precedence are wrong.

Comment: `is` happens before `and` for the same reason that `*` happens before `+`. All operators in Python have precedence, not just the usual PEMDAS you learn about in early mathematics.

Comment: I skipped these (or don't remember) when I was learning lol. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

> (None and None is None)

"is" has a priority, so `None is None` returns `True`

"and" executed after that, so `None and True` result in `None`

If you add parenthesis, you can make it work in another way:
`((None and None) is None)` returns `True`

You can find more info on that topic here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence